# Могут ли быть вводными словами наречия " потом", а потом"?

Tags: вводные-слова

1)  "Будем, **во-первых** и прежде всего, добры, **потом честны**, **а потом** — не будем никогда забывать друг об друге" (Ф. Достоевский). Идет перечисление: "во-первых, потом,  а потом". (Последнее тире скорее  связано с разной структурой называемых признаков). Судя по пунктуации,  "потом" здесь просто **необособленное наречие**, хотя заменяет вводное слово "во-вторых".

Другие примеры: "Главные причины злополучия, постигшего нашу армию, были: во-первых, голод, **потом беспрерывные переходы и кочевья** и, наконец уже, стужа, когда она была сопряжена со снегом. (Д. В. Давыдов). Вот современная речь:  "Во-первых, дикарям чужды любовь и сострадание, **а потом закон такой**, понимаете? Чтобы выжить".

2) Собственно говоря, вопрос возник при анализе ранее приведенного здесь предложения "Во-первых, я не заметил, что это пример, **а потом, действительно**, в этом примере может быть и прошедшее время".

А если предложение перестроить, **то нужны запятые?** "Во-первых, я не заметил, что это пример, а потом ()в этом примере ()действительно () может быть прошедшее время". Такое впечатление, что запятые не нужны, паузы точно нет.

3) С другой стороны, возможна структура предложения с паузой, например: "**Во-первых**, почему кто-то должен им давать заказ, **а потом**, разве они сами не могут провести исследования?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Может ли “потом” быть вводным словом?***

Может. См. у [**Розенталя: XXVI. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ ПРИ СЛОВАХ, ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИ НЕ СВЯЗАННЫХ С ЧЛЕНАМИ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm)

> **Одни и те же слова могут употребляться то в качестве вводных** (стало быть, не членов предложения), **то в качестве членов
>   предложения** (чаще всего сказуемых или обстоятельств). Ср.:
>
> *И **потом** он стал знаменитым* («затем, после этого»). – *И, **потом**, он в моих глазах знаменитость* («кроме того»).

Comment: Спасибо, slava, за ответ, но меня интересует частная ситуация: наречие "потом" в значении во-вторых при наличии вводного слова "во-первых".  В предложении "Во-первых, я не заметил, что это пример, а потом, действительно, в этом примере может быть и прошедшее время" это наречие или вводное слово? Как определить синтаксическую роль "потом" в таких предложениях?

Comment: Как определить? К примеру, заменой "потом" на синонимичное ему в этом предложении вводное "кроме того" или "во-вторых"(убрав для лучшего понимания функции "потом" вводное "действительно"): _Во-первых, я не заметил, что это пример, **а кроме того / а во-вторых**, в этом примере может быть и прошедшее время._

Comment: Но в приведенных мною примерах запятая не ставится. И в предложении "Во-первых, я не заметил, что это пример, а потом в этом примере  действительно  может быть прошедшее время" тоже вроде бы нет запятых, хотя можно поставить обособленное  "а во-вторых" вместо "а потом".