# Почему в данном предложении выбрано двоеточие вместо возможного тире?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, авторская-пунктуация, частица, тире-или-двоеточие

Предложение из книги Б. Акунина:

*Теперь пора **объяснить про кличку** «Ластик». Она возникла не из-за того, что наш герой был маленький. И не из-за того, что он был какой-нибудь квадратный или, **там**, очень упругий, а из-за имени. **Оно уж точно было необыкновенное: Эраст.***

**Это известная тема**, и мы знаем, что знаки в некоторых случаях (или даже достаточно часто) **взаимозаменяемы.** Но почему именно в этом предложении выбрано пояснение, а не распространение/присоединение? (**Агрессивное** оно такое, это тире, всячески притесняет классическое двоеточие.)

Немного странно видеть здесь после двоеточия всего лишь **одно слово**, да и речь перед конечной (ожидаемой) паузой вдруг как бы резко **останавливается** на другой длинной паузе после двоеточия.

**Попутные вопросы** по этому тексту:

(1) Вызывает сомнение падежное управление в сочетании "***объяснить про кличку***".
(2) Использование наречия "***там***" в качестве вводного слова нормируется?

**P. S.** Пожалуйста, отвечайте по возможности в поле ответа...

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В усечённом предложении тире будет предпочтительней:
*Оно было необыкнов**Е**нное – Эраст.* Перед именем идёт повышение тона.
А здесь, после предыдущего предложения, в котором интонационно выделяются прилагательные *квадратный* и *упругий*, ударение уже смещается:
*Оно уж т**О**чно было необыкновенное: Эраст.* Перед именем – полное понижение тона, почти как в конце предложения, а это одно из условий употребления двоеточия. (Хотя я, конечно, и в этом случае поставил бы тире.)

**О попутных вопросах** (они, кстати, меня больше заинтересовали):

**1.** Может, глагол «объяснить» в этом случае становится косвенно-переходным – присоединяющим существительное со значением объекта в винительном падеже с предлогом?
«Объяснить кличку» не скажешь. Добавить слова или целые придаточные? *Объяснить причину... объяснить, почему* – а не навредит ли это художественности и раскованности? Заменить глагол? А зачем? Сайт «Картаслов.ру», например, собрал много [предложений со словосочетанием «объяснить про»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE).

> И стал как ни в чём не бывало **объяснять про** прилагательные: какие из них качественные, какие притяжательные, какие относительные и как их отличать.
> *Дмитрий Емец, Король хитрости, 2004.*

**2.** «[Там](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC)» в этом предложении ну уж никак не наречие.
Из статьи [Нужно ли ставить запятую перед словом «там»?](https://yandexwebcache.net/yandbtm?fmode=inject&tm=1686218603&tld=ru&lang=ru&la=1685930880&text=%22%2C%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%2C%22&url=https%3A//orfographia.ru/tam-zapyataya-nuzhna-ili-net/&l10n=ru&mime=html&sign=6d4f5852e3815060afed0ad6ab7b67ab&keyno=0):
«там» может быть частицей, не имеющей полноценного лексического значения, а только вносящей в высказывание различные оттенки чувств.

> *Хорошо, если ты, к примеру, в речку упадёшь **или там** в озеро.*
> *Не хочет, так пусть болтает в лесу с белками **или там,** скажем, с курами на заднем дворе!* (**Частица в сочетании с разделительным союзом**.)
> *И будете ходить к врачу **или, там,** психологу и платить ему.*
> *Вы ведь наверняка учитесь складывать, вычитать, делить и умножать и делаете это не ради учителя **или, там,** директора.* (**Авторская пунктуация**.)

Вот и у Акунина выбрано обособление. Хоть двусмысленности не возникает, но «он был квадратный или там очень упругий» выглядит и читается некрасиво: *где там?* :)
В конце концов есть [куча частиц, которые обособляются](https://grammatika-rus.ru/obosoblenie-chastits-2/?amp): *ан нет, глядь, мол, дескать, что ли* и др. Можно сказать, что выделение «там» факультативно.

Comment: Александр, спасибо, прекрасный ответ! Чуть позже напишу свои замечания (надо подумать и т.д.)

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к ответу Александра**

Я с благодарностью принимаю ответ, но дополнительно приведу свои мысли по темам.

1. *Оно уж тОчно было необыкновенное: **Эраст**.*

Я согласна с двоеточием у Акунина, там явно определяется **пояснительный** характер второго сообщения  (необыкновенное, а какое именно?). Но «агрессивное» тире уже и здесь "присматривается" к предложению, ведь оно тоже может обозначать пояснение. К тому же **структура** не располагает к постановке двоеточия – одно слово, конец предложения.

В ответе очень правильно сделано **сравнение** двух предложений и поставлено ударение во втором. Но вот написано: «Хотя я, конечно, и в этом случае поставил бы тире». Да, вероятно, многие сделали бы так же…

2. ***Объяснить про кличку***.

На слух сочетание кажется некорректным, да и в словаре нет указания на возможную непереходность. С другой стороны, на практике предложное управление используется часто, а это говорит о **необходимости** такой конструкции.

3. **"Там" в качестве вводного слова.**

Да, это частица, а не наречие  – признаться, я проглядела этот момент, а ведь есть указание в словаре. (Уважаемые пользователи, всегда читайте словарь, причем внимательно!)

Но возникает вопрос:  это **частица** (нет обособления) или частица в функции обособленного **вводного слова**? На практике используются оба варианта, но речь идет о **нормировании** второго. В источниках мне не встречалась эта информация.

**P. S.** Нашелся интересный материал про обособление местоименного наречия "***потом***" в функции вводного слова: [Могут ли быть вводными словами наречия "потом", "а потом"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426681/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Сомневался, писать или не писать, какой знак поставил бы я. Ну да, даже не задумываясь, нарисовал бы тире. // По ссылке посмотрел, согласен, что "потом" может выступать в значении вводного и обособляться.

Comment: Частицы вроде бы вводными не бывают. Наречие в функции вводного, вот ссылка: https://i.imgur.com/AyA0WCw.png В таких случаях значение "допустим". В словарях другое.

Comment: Всякое бывает... КОНЕЧНО. I. частица. Употр. при выражении согласия, подтверждения сказанного; да, разумеется. Есть будешь? - К.! Вы говорите по-английски? - К.! II. вводн. сл. Разумеется, несомненно. К., привычка много значит. Вы, к., к нам придёте? А вы дайте, пожалуйста, другую ссылку на ресурс, по вашей непонятен источник сообщения. Хочется внимательно прочитать этот словарь (автор, год издания).   А вы вроде бы заскучали?  А то там есть два интересных вопроса по пунктуации...

Comment: Смотрю, что они вводное слово считают отдельной частью речи. Тогда вводное по своей природе. А в других случаях какая-то часть речи употребляется в функции вводного. Это из словаря вводных слов. В одном нет распространителя, а что второе, не знаю.

Comment: Олид, ну это отдельная тема, я не буду больше здесь ее обсуждать. Поезд от этой станции уже УШЕЛ, впереди новые темы и новые задачи. "Вперед ту,да,  куда никто не звал..." У меня такое отношение к новым и старым вопросам, не люблю возвращаться к прошедшему времени.

Comment: Это вы очень зря. Как человек, который постоянно хочет новое, а старое не доделывает и бросает. Это не профессиональный подход.

Comment: Я все доделала, что мне было нужно, ага?  А наука о прошлом называется археологией, но я не археолог и не антиквар:)  Ну это, конечно,  как кому нравится...

Comment: Это, конечно, смешно. Археология в языке — это этимология. Остальное так называть нельзя. Понимаю, если речь о вопросах, заданных давно, а здесь только два дня прошло. Просто жесть.

Comment: Так надо было раньше приходить. Но вы можете добавить свой ответ с точной ссылкой,  а я вам за это плюсик подставлю и приму его к сведению. Идет?

Comment: Этого словаря нет онлайн. Ссылки на  страницу нет.

Comment: Так найдите, а иначе я не могу принять к сведению неизвестный источник. До свидания.

Comment: Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений Остроумовой и Фрамполь 2010.

Comment: Пожалуйста, запишите это в поле ответа, а то комментарии удалят. И считайте, что я уже приняла это к сведению. Спасибо.

Comment: Ой, 2009. Прочитал одно, а написал другое, округлил :)

Answer (score 1):

Справочник вводных слов Фрамполь:

> ТАМ, **наречие**; разг. Употребляется в функции **вводного**
> для логического выделения части, обычно с целью пояснения,
> уточнения: Вот ждет его какой-нибудь проситель, **там**
> директор магазина, четыре часа, а он все не идет; И им не
> жалко было послать, **там**, тетушке из Киева или дядюшке из
> Мариуполя посылку.

Насчет *объяснить* вопрос интересный. Можно заметить разную смысловую нагрузку у дополнений

```
Объясни хоть что-нибудь про кличку
Расскажи об этом хоть что-нибудь
```

Данные предложения можно разобрать по-разному, либо как два дополнения к глаголу, либо как дополнение к дополнению. Перед нами так называемые дуплексивы

Comment: Спасибо за ваш мнение, вопрос оказался сложнее, чем я думала. У меня есть предположение (как объяснить разное написание "там" в словаре, ну и обособление его в примере из книги), но хотелось бы еще кого-то послушать. Чтобы определить правильность, ответа (в том числе своего), желательно сравнить его с другими точками зрения. Поэтому я не тороплюсь отвечать первой. Это как в велосипедной гонке, быть лидером (отвечать первым) стратегически не всегда выгодно, особенно на длинных дистанциях :)

Comment: @Sharon Чего разное? Что имеется в виду?

Comment: Имеется в виду, что один словарь трактует вводное "там" как наречие, а другой видимо как-то иначе

Comment: Нашла словарь 2009 года, и в обоих примерах слово "там" ОБОСОБЛЕНО как вводное, а примеры те же самые. Но в практических текстах встречаются обе формы. Как сделать выбор и объяснить его?